# Javascript variable contains plain text including html tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is the js code

```
function startChatSession(){  
$.ajax({
  url: "chat.php?action=startchatsession",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    username = data.username;

    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        if (item)   { // fix strange ie bug

            chatboxtitle = item.f;

            if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).length <= 0) {
                createChatBox(chatboxtitle,1);
            }

            if (item.s == 1) {
                item.f = username;
            }

            if (item.s == 2) {
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxinfo">'+item.m+'</span></div>');
            } else {
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.f+':&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+item.m+'</span></div>');
            }
        }
    });
```

here +item.m+ holds a plain text

if it contains html tags then it returns html tags also

for example +item.m+ contains

```
<b>Hello</b>
```

i want output to be

**Hello**

but i am getting same output as

```
<b>Hello</b>
```

this code is implemented in a IM chat and i need html code to be executed in the chat window. . .so please help me by suggesting to get html execution here

Thank you

Comment: It looks like `item.m` is probably using HTML entities rather than literal `<` and `>` characters.

Comment: The HTML tags in `item.m` must be encoded using htmlentities or something like that. Therefore, they don't get interpreted by the browser as HTML tags.

Comment: Check if the output is html -encoded, e.g. it's actually `&lt;b&gt;Hello...`.

Comment: check my answer out, to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have `&lt;b&gt` instead of a real `<br>`, to fix it do this:

```
var itemText = item.m
    .replace(/&lt;b&gt;/g, '<b>')
    .replace(/&lt;\/b&gt;/g, '</b>');
```

then use `itemText` instead of `item.m` in the code, like this:

```
        var itemText = item.m
            .replace(/&lt;b&gt;/g, '<b>')
            .replace(/&lt;\/b&gt;/g, '</b>'); 
        if (item.s == 2) {
            $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxinfo">'+itemText+'</span></div>');
        } else {
            $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.f+':&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+itemText+'</span></div>');
        }
```

and if you want to do it for some other tags like this:

```
<a href="chat.php">Hello</a>
```

you can do this like:

```
var itemText = item.m
    .replace(/&lt;\/a&gt;/g, '</a>')
    .replace(/&lt;a/g, '<a')
    .replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
```

Comment: can u please tell what would be the replace code for <a href="chat.php">Hello</a> , Thanks

Comment: @Raj: I updated my answer for `<a href="chat.php">Hello</a>`.

Comment: and what about double quotes??

Comment: double quotes usually don't change, `<a href="chat.php">Hello</a>` is like `&lt;a href="chat.php"&gt;Hello&lt;/a&gt;` and the only problems are `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 1):

On the PHP side, don't use htmlentities() to encode the content that you return. When you do, the server returns the HTML code of the character `<` and `>`, respectively `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: on php side i have $chat['message'] = sanitize($chat['message']); , what it means

Comment: sanitize is function defined in your code, check what it does. I bet you anything it calls htmlentities()

Comment: sorry, i have found function sanitize($text) {
 $text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
        $text = str_replace("\n\r","\n",$text);
 $text = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$text);
 $text = str_replace("\n","<br>",$text); } this function

Comment: htmlspecialchars is what is encoding your HTML characters. Try removing it.

Comment: removing it stopped loading messages :(

Comment: Then you might want to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are receiving encoded text from your server. Trying applying unescape() on your string before concatenating your strings.

Answer (score 1):

Decode the HTML entities , using .html jQuery function decodes the entities

```
item.m = $('<div>').html(item.m).text();
```

but I recommend you to remove the entities on server side, I see you are developing a chat so you better remove any HTML tags for security concerns not sure how are you working with the messages but users sometimes can do cross site scripting.